# How to keep the git local changes without commit and apply to different repos after switch

Tags: git

Let say I am working in branch-X and made some changes (about 50 files). Rather committing those to branch-X I want to commit those changes to branch-Y. So how to do this without committing in  branch-X. Just to add, there are few files which are related to branch-X changes.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the easiest approach here would be to just stash your working directory on branch `X`, and then apply that stash to branch `Y`:

```
# on branch X
git stash
git checkout Y
git stash apply
```

Note that you may get merge conflicts when you apply the stash, and you would have to resolve those.

It *might* also be possible to just checkout branch `Y` directly and then make a commit, but I am not sure if this would work out if there are files being added/removed.  In that case, stash is probably a safer bet.

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
git checkout Y
# (any git adds here)
git commit
```

Changes in your index or worktree remain there until you commit.

If your work is in files that already differ between the two branches you can

```
git checkout -m Y
```

to merge the changes.  There may be conflicts you have to resolve, but you'd have to resolve them anyway.